# Figwheel - Not reloading to browser (flappy-bird demo)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

Just starting with Figwheel. I downloaded the demo app found [here](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel)

And it runs fine in the browser, except that it isn't reloading when I make changes and save the file. Tried different editors/different browsers, etc.

I am cd'd into the directory, I ran `lein figwheel`... am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
When I run `tail -f figwheel_server.log` nothing comes up either. Not even when reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to El Capitan fixed it. *sigh*

Comment: Make sure you check the javascript console. You should see messages in the console about the browser trhing to make a connection to the figwheel repl. This is required for the reload functionality to work. If your not seeing any messages in the console, then hour browser is not connecting to giwheel. Also, when you start figwheel, does it return the prompt or does it have a msg saying it will return the prompt once the connection is made?

Comment: Hey Tim, Upgrading to El Cap fixed it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure you are changing a file that will actually trigger a reload. Figwheel will not reload changes made to `html` files.

Next, check you have a `:figwheel` configuration inside your `:cljsbuild` build target. This enables you to specify different figwheel options for different targets.

Finally, also check you have a `:figwheel` config *outside* your `:builds`. This allows for specifying project level settings, such as CSS locations.

An example might look like:

```
:cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "dev"
        :source-paths ["src"]
        :figwheel { :on-jsload "project.core/on-js-reload" }}]}

    :figwheel {
        :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]})
```

Also note that the *'examples'* directory of fighweel states:

> This is really not an example project It's a big hodgepodge project
>   that I use to test various figwheel features.

So if you are trying to copy that directly, you are better off reading through the documentation and starting a new project.

A good way to start this is to use the provided leiningen template:

`lein new figwheel hello-world`

Comment: In the sample, it includes all of these things and still doesn't work. I'll try making a new project.